# Rails POST request to Eventbrite not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, http, eventbrite

I am trying to POST(create) an event using EventBrite's API.

I have the auth key but am having trouble formatting the request.

Here is what I have.

```
def self.syndicate_event
    event = Event.first
    body_string =
    "{
        'event': {
            'name': {
              'html': #{event.name}
            },
            'description': {
              'html': #{event.description}
            },
            'start': {
              'utc': #{event.start},
              'timezone': #{event.start_timezone},
            },
            'end': {
              'utc': #{event.end},
              'timezone': #{event.end_timezone},
            },
            'currency':#{event.currency}
        }
    }"
    json_body = body_string.to_json
    respo = HTTP.auth("Bearer mytoken")
    .post("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/",
            params: json_body
          )
  end
```

It gives me : 'Can't convert String into Array.' error. Any ideas what is going on ? And if someone has used the API for EventBrite, is there a better way other than formatting my string like that and then making it into JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the EventBrite API, but it looks like the json_body string is malformed. You can verify that your json is valid by doing `JSON.parse(json_body)` and that should return a hash representation of your json. If it's malformed, it will raise an error.

I would opt to use the `to_json` method on a hash instance to guarantee the json will not be malformed.

Something like:

```
body_object = 
    { event: {
        name: {
          html: event.name
        },
        description: {
          html: event.description
        }...,
        currency: event.currency }
    }
json_body = body_object.to_json
```